# there is an library which i used react-native-pie for pie chat

Tags: android, react-native

[image]

I'm using react-native-pie library for pie chart its working fine in iOS but in android, it's showing like black screen .what I need to do work in android

```
import Pie from 'react-native-pie'
<Card style={{flex:0.5}}>
              <CardItem style={{height:250}}>
                <View style={{flexDirection:'column'}}>
                      <View style={{flexDirection:'row'}}>
                        <Text style={styles.text1}>Occupied</Text>
                        <Text style={styles.text2}>{sold2}</Text>
                        <Image style={styles.image2} source= 
                          {require('./icons/ww.png')}/>

                      </View>
                      <View>
                          <Pie
                            radius={70}
                            innerRadius={45}
                            series={[sold]}
                            colors={['#FF8C00']}
                            backgroundColor={'#ddd'} />
                          <View style={styles.gauge}>
                            <Text style={[styles.gaugeText, 
                               {color:'#FF8C00'}]}>{sold}%</Text>
                          </View>
                      </View>
                    </View>
              </CardItem>
            </Card>
```